# Captive Nut For PCB Grounding

Tags: pcb, components, ground, grounding

I need to affix a ground strap to my PCB. A strap similar to [image: this one].

Ideally I want to simply screw this to the board. Are there captive nuts available for this purpose? I can't find anything via a standard source Digi-key or Mouser. I see that PEM makes some but after inquiring I have to order a full reel. That's much more than I need or want.

Also, is there anything else I need to be concerned with in this situation?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Yes! These are a good alternative to what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]  [image]

There are [PCB-mount screw terminals](http://www.keyelco.com/products/sprod10.asp?CategoryID=9). Female thread on top, throughole pins on the bottom. Kind of a nut, which is soldered to a PCB.  These are avaible on Mouser and DigiKey in small quantities.

Use a star washer too, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Those look like really large lugs to be connecting directly to a PCB.  I would be concerned about mechanical stress imparted into the board by the ground straps unless you've got an unusually thick PCB.

[PEM is the standard](http://www.pemnet.com/fastening_products/circuit_board.html) for this type of product.  They offer a wide range of options, though some require specialized tooling for installation.

Another option would be to use brass or aluminum threaded hex standoffs ([McMaster-Carr](http://www.mcmaster.com/#catalog/118/3263/=j70vv6) or others).  Use one fastener to attach your board to the standoff and another to attach your ground strap to the standoff.  They offer them in standard sizes up to 3/8" fasteners (which looks about like what you need).  You could use a thread locking compound on the board-to-standoff fastener to prevent it from causing headaches when working with the ground strap fastener.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I should note the dimensions of the strap pictured aren't accurate but the style is. Figure that these will be attached to .062 FR4 with a #4 screw.

Comment: Ah; that makes a lot more sense.  The standoff approach will still work; you can use a short standoff and a button head cap screw for low profile on the underside of the PCB.