# grounding connection?

Tags: safety, prototyping, grounding, component-selection

What's the easiest way to connect a ring terminal to the ground terminal of an AC outlet? Are there plugs you can buy that make this easy?

I don't need (or want) the line and neutral wires accessible, just the ground terminal, for safety reasons.

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design!

Comment: WTF? The site says Electrical Engineering and its FAQ includes electrical engineering. Electrical and electronic prototyping often requires safety grounds. I am merely asking for some help in finding a convenient method to do so, and would treat this question no differently than other questions on soldering irons or grounding safety questions.

Comment: This question is in the same general area and nobody had any objections to it: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39780/captive-nut-for-pcb-grounding?rq=1

Comment: @JasonS  IMO, that's a higher quality question.  With a picture.

Comment: @Jason: The FAQ excludes shopping questions.

Comment: @LeonHeller: Please try to provide useful *reasons* for why any given question should be closed. Simply repeating that single sentence, [as you historically have](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/305/leon-heller?tab=activity&sort=comments), is incredibly unhelpful. One might think your ISP is charging by the word.

Comment: See the FAQ! It's nothing to with electronic design and it's a shopping question.

Comment: @LeonHeller: I agree with you, just not with how you said it. Your reply to me is a good start, though. How about you include a link to the FAQ when telling new users that their question is not on topic? Or, as you said in your reply, tell the user why **specifically** their question is off topic (e.g. shopping question). I hope you'll agree with me that that is much more helpful than your usual blanket claim.

Comment: It's up to people to read the FAQ before they post!

Comment: It's not a shopping question, and quite frankly I find that assertion insulting. I just want to know if there is a way to easily attach a ring terminal (as is common in grounding straps, whether premade or hand made) to the ground terminal of an AC outlet. If there is an easy and reliable way to make something myself out of standard parts, I will. If there is a pre-existing part that accomplishes this which someone has heard about, I would like to know. I don't see how that's any different than asking if there are ICs that can handle PLLs or generate frequency sweeps.

Comment: FWIW I used to be a frequent contributor on this site and StackOverflow, but the attitudes around here made me lose interest. Think about that if you want to retain people on your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to get a replacement plug and just only connect to the ground pin.

[image]

This isn't as cheap as Michael's solution, but its easier to move from place to place.

Comment: have you used these plugs before? what kind of connection happens inside the plug? (e.g. screw terminals? solder? crimp?) I looked + couldn't find a detailed datasheet.

Comment: All replacement plugs, which I've seen so far, had screw terminals inside.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to attach a wire that has a ring terminal on the end of it to an outlet is to remove the cover plate screw, replace the screw with one that is unpainted and install the ring terminal under the screw.

This approach is validated through the design of this three prong to two prong converter device.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That was my first thought, but it's not always present. In my cubicle I have outlets w/o a ground screw.